# cannot display child component into parent

Tags: angular

I have a parent component `ViewCalendars`

**view-calendars.component.html**

```
 <div class="container-calendar">
      <ca-month-header>
      </ca-month-header>
  </div>
```

**view-calendars.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';  
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MonthHeaderComponent } from './ca-month-header/month-header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ca-view-calendars',
  templateUrl: './view-calendars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-calendars.component.css']
})
export class ViewCalendarsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MonthHeaderComponent) header: any;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and a child component `MonthHeader`

**month-header.component.html**

```
<div class="month-header">
  <div class="month">
    <label> Month </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**month-header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ca-month-header',
  templateUrl: './month-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./month-header.component.css']
})
export class MonthHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and this is what I get in DevTools.

[image]

I have imported the components in the module and I don't understand why the child component it's not displayed

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you declared both the components into app.module.ts file ?

Comment: Try a prod build it will complie and tell you if you have any errors before rendering `ng build --prod` or `ng build --aot`

Answer (score 1):

Are there any errors on the Angular compiler console?

If there aren't, I would suggest that you try to print something different in the Month header component, like something in a `h2` tag, and see if it prints. You should also confirm if your components are declared and imported properly in the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your App is not compiling the month component.

Here is what you need to do . :

Declare both the components in `app.module.ts` file  :

```js
// in app.module.ts file 
import { MonthHeaderComponent } from './month-heder/month-heder.component';
import { ViewCalendarsComponent } from './view-calendars/view-calendars.component';

@NgModule({

  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],

  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,MonthHeaderComponent,ViewCalendarsComponent ],

  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]

})

export class AppModule { }



then, where ever you want to use, use the components selectors to render them , like below  :
```

```html
<!-- IN parent component.html file -->

<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
Parent child relation ships in angular  :  
</p>

<div class="container">
  <h1> This App component  parent </h1>
<div class="calendar-container">
  <!-- Declaring view calendars as child of App.component.ts -->
  <ca-view-calendars> </ca-view-calendars>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the working stackblitz example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfqdzn